# Creating a HTML search function for google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, html, spreadsheet

I have been willing to make a simple google spreadsheet search function in HTML. All tutorials found couldn't help me. I'm trying to use a HTML input/form that searches for a value in my spreadsheet and displays the result row(s) on my webpage. I would hope someone could help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script? I think that by this, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, I want to make a html code with an input tagg that uses the google sheets api to search for a row in my google spreadsheet and sends it back to display on my webpage.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.